# Understanding a metric with prescribed range

Tags: metric-spaces

I have the following question in my book:

> Show that any subset $A$ of the set of non negative reals with $0 \in A$, is the set of all distances between points of some metric spaces.

And the solution is given to be:

For a given set $A$ of non negative reals with $0 \in A$ , we define a function $ d: A \times A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by  $$ d(x,y) =
 \begin{cases}
\text{max}\{x,y\}, & \text{if}  x \neq y \\
0 , & \text {if} x=y
\end {cases}
$$

Then $d$ is clearly a Metric on $A$ and for any $x \in A$ , $d(0,x) = x$ ; also for any $x , y \in A $ , $d(x,y) = \text{max}(x,y)$ or $0$ so that $d(x,y) \in A$. Thus $(A,d)$ is the required metric space.

Now my question is: Is the metric taken in the solution fixed? Can we take any other metric e.g the usual metric or any other metric on $A$?

My next question is there any special significance of the 'max' metric used in the solution on any space? By special I mean like the usual metric is the usual distance between points in the co-ordinate plane, such as if this metric has any significance.

Comment: The d you have defined is not a metric as the $\Delta$ inequality fails.  Let $x=0, y=10, z=10$.  The$d(x,y)+d(y,z)=9+0 < 10=d(x,z)$

Comment: How $d(x,y) = 9 $ ? $\text{max} \{0,10 \} = 10 $ I think.

Comment: You're right.  I mixed up two examples I was trying.

Comment: It is easy to furnish a metric on $A$: any metric on $\mathbb{R}_+$ can be restricted appropriately as needed. It's also not that hard to furnish a metric whose range *contains* $A$, for example the standard metric does this, as would any other metric satisfying $d(0,x)=x$. But generally the range of the standard metric will contain *other* elements too, for example when $A=\{ 0,1,3 \}$ the standard metric has $2$ in its range. So I'm not sure how you would make the range of $d$ be *exactly* equal to $A$ except this way.

Comment: @Mathemagical . You probably have noticed by now that  for non-negative $x,y,z,$ if $x\ne y\ne z \ne x$ then $d(x,z)=\max (x,z)\leq  x+z\leq  \max (x,y)+\max (y,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes.  But thanks for writing it out.  This d is actually quite cool.  Bends my intuition a bit to see this metric which ignores the size of the smaller of the two numbers altogether.

Comment: @Mathemagical .With this metric every $p\in A$ \ $\{0\}$ is an isolated point for if $0\ne p\in A$ then the open ball of radius $p/2$ centered at $p$ contains only the point $p$. 
 And if $0\in A$ then $0$ is also isolated $unless$ $ \inf (A\setminus \{0\})=0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Cool.  Is see that what you say is true. Metric spaces are amongst the least strange topological spaces and even amongst them there are some strange ones.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the metric taken in the solution fixed?

If you mean "is it unique", the answer is no. For example, take any bijection $\varphi:A\to A$ and let $d_\varphi(x,y) = \max(\varphi(x), \varphi(y)) $ for $x\ne y$.  More generally, let $B$ be any set of the same cardinality as $A$ and define $d_\varphi$ on $B$ as above, using a bijection $\varphi:B\to A$. This is described as "pulling a metric back by $\varphi$".

Also, the underlying set need not have the same cardinality as $A$. Given any set $X$, we can define a metric on $A\times X$ by 
$d((a,x),(a',x'))=\max (a,a')$ unless $(a,x)=(a',x')$. In particular, we  can put such a metric on $A\times \mathbb{R}$ and then pull it back to $\mathbb{R}$ by some bijection $\mathbb{R}\mapsto A\times \mathbb{R}$.

> any special significance of the 'max' metric

It has a reasonable interpretation as the required fuel capacity of a plane that has to fly from $x$ to $y$ with a required stopover at $0$, where it is refueled.

It's also an example of a [ultrametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space), meaning $d(x,y)\le \max(d(x,z), d(y,z))$. Absent any assumptions on the structure of $A$, we pretty much have to use an ultrametric: given that we must have a triangle with two side length $a,b\in A$, what should the third sidelength of the triangle be? We don't know if any other elements of $A$ (if they even exist) can fit the triangle inequality. Using the smaller of $a,b$ risks violating the triangle inequality, if it happens to be less than half of the larger. So the only safe choice is to have the third side be $\max(a,b)$. Hence, an ultrametric. Notice that $\max$ function comes up naturally here.

Comment: My first doubt is cleared, while the significance of the 'max' metric is not totally cleared ! Hope to get it in future. Thank you for your answer. @Michelle.

Comment: If by significance you mean "is it used anywhere except to solve this problem", the answer is probably no.